# Is it legal to piggyback an existing indoor outlet to a new outdoor outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, outdoor

I just had a deck installed and wanted to install an outdoor outlet from the inside outlet. It is just on the other side of the interior wall where it would be installed.

Is this legal?

Comment: What circuit is the interior outlet on?

Comment: Since this is a legal question it would be good to get authoritative advice.  I believe this would depend on the building codes in your jurisdiction.  You could either "just do it" or you could ask the proper authorities for their opinion on the subject.

Comment: It's not a legal question like "what's the statute of limitations for suing my contractor".  It's a legal question only insofar as Code is the law. That's not forbidden here, it's *mandatory*: this forum's rules require Code-compliant answers.